# Unable to list AWS/EC2 ,AWS/S3, AWS/Glue namespace metric for cloudwatch exporter prometheus

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch

I am currently using **prom/cloudwatch-exporter:latest** image for working with cloudwatch exporter for my prometheus server. i can able to list

```
'AWS/Lambda', 'AWS/ApplicationELB', 'AWS/Firehose', 'AWS/RDS', 'AWS/AutoScaling', 'AWS/ElasticBeanstalk'
```

but when i try to add 'AWS/EC2' it does not display any other values in prometheus dropdown. it is also observed that it does not list values for AWS/S3,AWS/Glue

not sure is it supported or not. or i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this might happen if there are no metric data to show for the time period selected in Prometheus for those services. Try to expand your time range.

Also, if the exporter is causing problems you could consider using an IAM role-based data source in Prometheus.